# How to send hex commands to turn projector on/off in node.js

Tags: node.js, serial-port, ip

I have a ViewSonic projector that I am trying to send rs232 commands to turn on and off.

This is the command to turn on:

```
0x06 0x14 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x34 0x11 0x00 0x00 0x5D
```

This is the command to turn off:

```
0x06 0x14 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x34 0x11 0x01 0x00 0x5E
```

This is the script:

```
const net = require('net');
const ping = require('ping');

const optomaCommands = {
    onCommand: "~0000 1\r\n",
    offCommand: "~0000 2\r\n"
};

const viewSonicCommands = {
    onCommand: Buffer.concat([
        Buffer.from([0x06, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x34, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x5D]),
        Buffer.from('\r\n')
    ]),
    offCommand: Buffer.concat([
        Buffer.from([0x06, 0x14, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x34, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x5E]),
        Buffer.from('\r\n')
    ])
};

const projectors = [
    {
        name: 'Optoma_1',
        ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx',
        port: 23,
        ...optomaCommands,
    },
    {
        name: 'viewSonic_pj',
        ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx',
        port: 23,
        ...viewSonicCommands,
    }
];

async function pingProjectors() {
    for (const projector of projectors) {
        const res = await ping.promise.probe(projector.ip);
        if (res.alive) {
            console.log(`Projector ${projector.name} at ${projector.ip} is reachable.`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Projector ${projector.name} at ${projector.ip} is not reachable.`);
        }
    }
}

function controlProjector(projector, command) {
    const client = new net.Socket();

    client.connect(projector.port, projector.ip, () => {
        console.log(`Connected to ${projector.name}`);
        client.write(command);
    });

    client.on('data', data => {
        console.log(`Received from ${projector.name}: ${data.toString('hex')}`);
        client.destroy();
    });

    client.on('close', () => {
        console.log(`Connection to ${projector.name} closed`);
    });

    client.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred:', err);
    });
}

// Turn off projectors
function turnOffAllProjectors() {
    for (const projector of projectors) {
        controlProjector(projector, projector.offCommand);
    }
}

// Turn on projectors
function turnOnAllProjectors() {
    for (const projector of projectors) {
        controlProjector(projector, projector.onCommand);
    }
}

// turnOffAllProjectors();

turnOnAllProjectors();

// pingProjectors();
```

Is this the correct way to use the commands? The commands for the Optoma projectors work fine.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Rather bizarre to terminate "*hex commands*" with CR and LF (ASCII control) characters! You mention "*rs232*" twice, but there's nothing in your "*script*" related to any sort of serial port!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! That gave me more clarity on what I need to fix in my script.